# c++ X11 global change cursor shape

Tags: c++, linux, x11, mouse-cursor

I'm writing a mouse emulation program for Linux based on input from external hardware (Leap Motion Controller).  For proper operation, I want to change the shape of the cursor to convey status information to the user related to their operation of the cursor.  I'm currently writing a user space program to handle this.  Mouse movement and mouse clicks are handled using the XTest library, but right now I can't find a way to change the shape of the cursor.

Using XDefineCursor() I've been able to change the cursor to a custom shape on a window owned by my program, but I need it in the full graphical environment, since this program will remain
hidden in the background most of the time.

I'd also prefer to not write a device driver and stay in user space for now if possible. Also I'd prefer to not have to change the code for the Display manager (ie Unity or LXDE).

Edit:
The hardware is the Leap Motion Controller.  I need to display to the user if they are still in the sensor's range, or outside the range.

Comment: What kind of external hardware do you have? Be more specific!

Answer (score 1):

You can watch for cursor changes with [XFixes protocol](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/fixesproto/fixesproto.txt) and then modify cursor each time it is changed adding your graphics to whatever window tried to set it ( SelectCursorInput/GetCursorImage/CursorNotify event)

Comment: It looks very promising, I just can't seem to find a lot of documentation on it.

Comment: I can give you simple example using c or javascript with https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11

Comment: @AndreySidorov: I'm looking to do something similar to OP, and debating whether to go digging in KDE to figure out how it does the bouncy cursor thing (when an app is starting), or tackle your suggested approach (is KDE doing the same thing?). I can't help but wonder whether chasing cursor changes would introduce race conditions and induce glitches (WM/app cursor change -> X11 wins update race and flushes display -> cursor monkey-patch -> X11 update => unpatched cursor is shown for one or two frames). I also remember the KDE bounce makes the cursor flicker badly on old PCs - can I fix that?